# MySQL Stored Procedures - Sending Variables that Might or Might Not Be Empty

Tags: mysql

I'm sending in a variable _activeflag which can be 1 or 0 (char, not smallint).  If I send in a blank for _activeflag, I want to get all records, but if I send in a 1 or 0, I want records with those activeflags so my where clause is

WHERE ( `activeflag` = _activeflag OR _activeflag = "" )

Is that not correct?  What exactly does that line mean?  I had convinced myself from some other page that I can't find that it's like a shorthand if statement.  If _activeflag is not blank then search on the column specified.  Am I wrong?

Comment: The where clause seems correct, although I'd flip the two sides of the `OR` clause for clarity. What exactly is the problem? Does it produce the wrong results?

Comment: Your query were right.

Comment: Is the field `activeflag` also a char?

Comment: The query is wrong, or at least incomplete, but the intention is correct.  WHERE *expression-involving-column* OR *expression-not-involving-column* gets optimized away when *expression-not-involving-column* is true, preventing the server from wasting time comparing the column to the variable, since the column comparison doesn't matter -- the OR is guaranteed to be true.  Similarly, if a query contains an expression evaluating a column AND  2 = 1 server will immediately return 0 rows, since it's impossible for 2 = 1 to ever be true, regardless of table data.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should probably check for `IS NULL` rather like

```
WHERE ( activeflag = _activeflag OR _activeflag IS NULL )
```

Comment: _activeflag is variable.

Comment: @RubahMalam, that's a parameter and it can be null if not passed anything.

Comment: Could be emptystring. If so, why don't use `... OR ifnull(_activeflag,'') = ''`?

Comment: @RubahMalam, it can be but generally an empty string won't be passed; rather the parameter won't be having any value and in such case it's better to check for is null.